# How to change location of a Hive metastore?

Tags: hadoop, datastax-enterprise

I recently decommissioned an analytics node with IP X.X.X.51. After this, I can't execute Shark queries since my Shark/Hive database is bound to the analytics node I just decommisioned:

```
shark> DESCRIBE DATABASE mykeyspace;
OK
mykeyspace      cfs://X.X.X.51/user/hive/warehouse/mykeyspace.db
```

According to the [Hive documentation for `ALTER DATABASE`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterDatabase) I can't change the location of my metadata database. How can I resolve this? Is there any other way for me to change the location IP of my store?

Comment: Was .51 your job tracker?

Comment: Yes. It was some time ago.

Comment: Did you try dsetool movejt

Comment: Yes, I did. And it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the location of it. Sad, but true.

However, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28112448/260805.