# Can't connect to CFS node

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

I removed (or decommisioned, can't remember) a DSE analytics node (with IP `10.14.5.50`) a couple of months ago. When I now try to execute a `dse shark` (`CREATE TABLE ccc AS SELECT ...`) query I now receiving:

```
15/01/22 13:23:17 ERROR parse.SharkSemanticAnalyzer: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: 0:0 Error creating temporary folder on: cfs://10.14.5.50/user/hive/warehouse/mykeyspace.db. Error encountered near token 'TOK_TMP_FILE'
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1053)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:8342)
    at shark.parse.SharkSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SharkSemanticAnalyzer.scala:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:284)
    at shark.SharkDriver.compile(SharkDriver.scala:215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:977)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:888)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.processCmd(SharkCliDriver.scala:347)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver$.main(SharkCliDriver.scala:240)
    at shark.SharkCliDriver.main(SharkCliDriver.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error connecting to node 10.14.5.50:9160 with strategy STICKY.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getScratchDir(Context.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getExternalScratchDir(Context.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getExternalTmpFileURI(Context.java:363)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.getMetaData(SemanticAnalyzer.java:1253)
    ... 12 more
```

I guess the above error is due to my keyspace referring to the old node:

```
shark> DESCRIBE DATABASE mykeyspace;
OK
mykeyspace      cfs://10.14.5.50/user/hive/warehouse/mykeyspace.db
Time taken: 0.997 seconds
```

**Is there any way for me to fix this incorrect database path?**

Tried (but failed) workaround to recreate the database: In `cqlsh` I created a keyspace `thekeyspace` and added a table `thetable`. I the opened up `dse hive` (and noticed that `DESCRIBE DATABASE thekeyspace` is giving me a correct `cfs` path). However, I am unable to drop the the database using `DROP DATABASE thekeyspace`.

Additional information:

- I have no external tables in my keyspace.
- Making the SELECT against the tables works.
- Setting `-hiveconf cassandra.host=WORKING_NODE_IP` does not help.
- The following commands return proper IP:s (ie. not `X.X.X.50`):

  - `dsetool listjt`
  - `dsetool jobtracker`
  - `dsetool sparkmaster`
- I am getting the same error when I execute the query using `dse hive`.
- No Shark variable is referring to `X.X.X.50` when I execute `set;` in its REPL.
- I am running DSE 4.5.

Comment: This looks related: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201401.mbox/%3C1390679046882-929.post@n3.nabble.com%3E

Comment: I am now working around the issue by changing one of my existing cluster nodes to IP 10.14.5.50. It's a ridiculous fix for a small problem, but I have yet to find a way to change the actual IP in Hive.

Comment: Starting to believe this should be considered a bug. Pinged DataStax on Twitter about this: https://twitter.com/jensrantil/status/558557186734170112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stumbled across [this](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.0/datastax_enterprise/ana/anaHivRecreate.html) page that says you need to `TRUNCATE "HiveMetaStore"."MetaStore"` (in `cqlsh`) after removing Hive nodes. That did the trick.