# Is it safe to execute `DROP DATABASE mykeyspace CASCADE` in DSE Hive?

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax

**Is it safe to execute `DROP DATABASE mykeyspace CASCADE` in DSE Hive? Will it remove Cassandra data? Or can I safely be sure that only Hive metadata is removed?** When I try executing this I have a table snapshot created around the same time, which makes me worried.

This question is somewhat related to [Can't connect to CFS node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088921/cant-connect-to-cfs-node).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I tried dropping a table and the equivalent table in Cassandra is still there.